# XHTML CSS 3 Column Layout

Tags: css, xhtml

I am new to the world of XHTML and CSS. I put together a page that requires 3 column layout. The code gives me the desired effect across Internet Explorer, Firefox and Google Chrome however am unsure if it is the correct way to code.

I have posted the code for it before it worked and after applying the necessary changes to make it work.

Questions

- Is this the correct way to code it?
- Is it the best way to code?
- What issues can I run into with the code?

**Before it worked**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />

    <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Sample page</title>

    <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" media="all" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

    html, body {

        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: medium;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: none; 
        text-decoration: none; 

    }

    img#bg {

        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

    }

    #wrapper {

        border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;

    }

    #header {

        background-color: orange;

    }

    #container {

        overflow: auto;

    }

    #leftnav {

        background-color: yellow;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;

    }

    #rightnav {

        background-color: blue;
        float: right;

    }

    #rightnav p {

        border: 1px solid #000000;
        font-size: small;
        font-style: italic;

    }


    #content {

        background-color: gray;

    }


    #footer {
        clear: both;
        background-color: green;

    }

    ul {

        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5px;

    }

    ul li {

        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;

    }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="background" id="bg" />
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>about</li>
                <li>contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="container">

            <div id="leftnav">
                <ol>
                    <li>Link 1</li>
                    <li>Link 2</li>
                    <li>Link 3</li>
                </ol>
            </div>

            <div id="rightnav">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                content
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**After it worked**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />

    <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Sample page</title>

    <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" media="all" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

    html, body {

        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: medium;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: none; 
        text-decoration: none;

    }

    img#bg {

        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

    }

    #wrapper {

        border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;

    }

    #header {

        background-color: orange;

    }

    #container {

        overflow: hidden;

    }

    #leftnav {

        background-color: yellow;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;

    }

    #rightnav {

        background-color: blue;
        float: right;
        width: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 1000px;
        margin-bottom: -1000px;

    }

    #rightnav p {

        border: 1px solid #000000;
        font-size: small;
        font-style: italic;

    }


    #content {

        background-color: gray;

    }


    #footer {
        clear: both;
        background-color: green;

    }

    ul {

        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5px;

    }

    ul li {

        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;

    }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="background" id="bg" />
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li>home</li>
                <li>about</li>
                <li>contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="container">

            <div id="leftnav">
                <ol>
                    <li>Link 1</li>
                    <li>Link 2</li>
                    <li>Link 3</li>
                </ol>
            </div>

            <div id="rightnav">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                content
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow that is a really broad question

Comment: @Kieran - How is it broad? I can update the question if need be.

Comment: @Kieran - not really broad - it's just to comment some code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is pretty much ok - few things you may do:

1.) You don't need to define properties that are set by default in the browser: `font-weight: normal;` is already the default browser value for body so you can omit that if you are not changing it's look.

2.) `margin: 0px;` does not need the px with it - do `margin: 0;`

3.) Name ids and classes with content-related names - not with layout related: `#rightnav` might be on the right side in your current css layout but one day you may change your mind and put it on left side and the id kinda looses some relevance. `#subnav` might be a better choice.

4.) Don't really understand what you wanted to acomplish with this bit of code (since i don't have time to setup a live site example):

```
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
```

but looks bit ugly altough it is perfectly valid and can do the job.

5.) `<img src="images/background.jpg" alt="background" id="bg" />` - If the image is a background and not content related use the css property `background-image` to apply it.

I won't comment on meta tags since I don't have enough knowledge about it.

Comment: @easwee- Thanks. The reason I have defined the properties such as `font-weight: normal` is for my own sake to understand what they do. I will certainly remove it as I get a better grasp of the different properties and their values. Thanks for the heads up. Point taken on the use of the unit for the margin property. As for the name ids and classes, the reason I named them as per the layout is so that it is easy to identify the part of the layout it affects.`#subnav` seems rather ambiguous.

Comment: @easwee- Also in terms of the structure of the code blocks, do you have any comments how it affects SEO? I posted a separate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050799/xhtml-and-search-engine-optimization

Comment: @easwee - The reason I used the padding and margin properties is because as the amount of text in the right navigation is far less and the background appears shorter in comparison to the one on the left. If you have the time, you'll see what I mean when you copy and paste the code. As for the image background, I did try and use background-image however it does not allow me to stretch considering the image is much small in dimension in comparison to the available screen size.

Comment: @easwee - `continued` - I understand that the property background-size is only supported in CSS 3 and is in draft as per the article - http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - How can you say #subnav is more ambiguos when it clearly states that the element is a sub navigation? #rightCol is way more ambiguous - it can be a navigation an add container, a video container...not to mention that by doing float:left when your customer decides to change the position totaly messes up the naming + you have to go edit the name in html to '#leftCol' if you want to keep your logic running in the css.

Comment: @easwee - Point taken regarding the navigation. What were you thoughts on the use of margin and padding as well as the use of the background?

Answer (score 0):

A few comments with regards to meta tags...

```
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
```

These meta tags are useless.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
```

The meta keywords used to matter. No search engines bother with it anymore as it's always abused.

```
<meta name="description" content="" />
```

And this meta tag is... well... not useless, but almost. The content within the page should all the describing for you.

Comment: Google recently had an article regarding the 'description' meta and advocates its use. http://goo.gl/YlLH3

Comment: @Patrick Fredriksson - When you say they are useless, why is that? I have seen a number of examples cite them. 
@Rob - Great. Will have a read of it.

Comment: @Rob Yes Google advocates it's use because they grab the description, sometimes. But when you search for specific words, Google still highlights those and any words surrounding it. So, it is rarely displayed.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey with regards to "imagetoolbar", have a look at http://www.metatags.org/meta_http_equiv_imagetoolbar. With regards to MSSmartTagsPreventParsing, this is a meta tag that Microsoft was planning to implement in IE6, but never did because they got a lot of flack for it.